# Accessing UI elements with a task

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, task-parallel-library, task

I have following start method, which actually starts a task:

```
    [STAThread]
    public void Start()
    {
        if (!this.cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {                
            SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
            this.t = Task.Factory.StartNew(
            () =>
            {
                var grid = new Grid
                {
                    Width = 200,
                    Height = 2000
                };                       
            }, 
            this.cancellationToken, 
            TaskCreationOptions.None, 
            TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());
            this.log.LogDebug(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Task " + this.TaskId + " is started"));
        }
        else
        {
            this.log.LogDebug(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "Cancellation is requested, Task " + this.TaskId + " will not start"));
        }          
    }
```

and I have defined the TaskScheduler to "FromCurrentSynchronizationContext since I want the task to execute and access a UI element (Grid) in order to check whether it has permission, but I'm receiving following error:

```
The calling thread must be STA, because many UI components require this
```

I thought that it will work by setting the TaskScheduler to "FromSynchronizationContext", but with no luck. Where is the issue in this case ?

Comment: Where are you launching your UI, it doesn't show in this code?

Comment: var grid = new Grid { Width = 200, Height = 2000 };  Is an UI element

Comment: Yea, I'm struggling to understand what you're doing there; but I _think_ the problem here is that the effect of that code is to attempt to initialize the UI *from* the background thread.  And you can't do that, you have to initialize the UI from the main `STAThread`, I suspect if you throw a `var x = new MainForm(); x.Show()` in there, the problem would go away.

Comment: You are trying to create UI component in threadpool thread. What is your primary intention?

Comment: I just want to check whether there is a way to let a task initialize a UI element. I just cannot find out how to do that. I have even used a dispatcher but with no luck.

Comment: Why are you doing this `SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());`?

Comment: By the way, `[STAThread]` only works on the main method.

Comment: Is `Start()` executed on the UI thread?

Comment: Yes, Start() is executed on UI thread

Answer (score -1):

Simply, remove this line:

```
SynchronizationContext.SetSynchronizationContext(new SynchronizationContext());
```

The `SynchronizationContext` is already set in GUI applications.

Please note that you can remove the `[STAThread]` attribute from the `Start` method since it does nothing here. This attribute is only valid on the entry point of the application, i.e., the `main` method.